# TiddlyWiki + Dropbox + Android

Tags: browser, dropbox

Greetings,

I keep a [Tiddlywiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) in my [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) folders, and I'd really like to be able to open/edit/view it on Android. Currently when I try to open the Tiddlywiki file, I am asked if I want to view it with:

- DB HTML Viewer
- HTMLViewer

and a few other options which don't seem relevant. Unfortunately, neither of these viewers seem to play real nice with the Tiddlywiki html layout, which makes it rather difficult for me to view/edit notes. Usually when I open my browser, I have useful zooming capabilities, which is what I'm sort of looking for. I'm running CyanogenMod, not sure if this is the default stock browser or not.

Is there any application I can download to get this to work, or any way that I can get my default browser application to show up in Dropbox's list?

Comment: Have you tried searching the market: https://market.android.com/search?q=tiddly+wiki&so=1&c=apps

Comment: @Lie thanks! I did actually take a look at that app a few months ago, and some comments about the app deterred me from it. I have since installed it, but alas it seems to be about the same as opening the wiki file in my browser. Maybe I should just switch to something like iTW, although this isn't the best solution for when I access it on my PC.

Comment: Similar, possibly - [Open HTML file from SD Card](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4775/open-html-file-from-sd-card). Can you navigate to the file in your Dropbox folder manually using a file manager?

Comment: @eldarerathis Sounds like it'll do the trick, I'll give it try! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this

http://tiddlyspot.com/

it basically creates a tiddly on a web server, so you can edit it with every android browser able to render it. You can download it, edit offline and when online sync it with the server version.

Opera Mobile is not able to edit offline a tiddlywiki and save changes. Firefox mobile can. Other browsers i dont know. Normally they need a .jar Java file which the mobile browsers often cant execute afaik.

Comment: Seems like a good solution, I'll give it a try later today!

Answer (score 3):

Try [AndTidWiki](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mgsimon.android.andtidwiki&hl=en). It's currently in beta, and it works well for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use Firefox. To support saving the wiki, install the "TiddlyFox" Firefox addon.

I tested this works today.  Also it could directly open an .html file with Firefox in file explorer like "ES File Explorer".

Remark: Seems TiddlyWiki v5 displays better than v2.8.1 on Android.

Answer (score 1):

Presently AndTidWiki is the best, or rather the only choice, that allows you to use your wiki straight from Dropbox. However, there are some small issues - like text overlap on zooming, which i hope will improve with further versions. 
I haven't been able to find any other tiddly browser that allows editing your wiki from dropbox.