# Generate a browser bookmark from file manager

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, asus-eee-pad-transformer, bookmarks, html

We are developing a web site that will all be local to an android tablet. The idea is we create the web app, copy the web app to MicroSD cards and distribute the SD cards.

Right now, when you open the file manager and browse to the location and open `index.html` , the file manager does a terrible job and displaying any of the HTML.

In order to view the page in a browser, you have to type: `file:///Removable/MicroSD/MyApp/index.html`

That isn't very intuitive. Is it possible to create a file that gets executed from the file manager that will create a bookmark and place it on the home screen that points to the location I stated above? Thanks.

Comment: Why not a shortcut from the launcher on Android itself? That seems easier...

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Long press on the home screen, a dialog will appear *Add to home screen*, there should be one called *Shortcuts*, then *Select Shortcut*, then its *Bookmark*...(**this will be dependent on the ROM, Launcher and Android version**)

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to be working. All I get is a wallpaper chooser

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by t0mm13b in his comment on your question, a shortcut on the desktop is the easiest way. This requires you to first open the page with your browser, and create a bookmark for it (you will see later why this step is required).

As you stated not to be able to add the shortcut in the usual way, here comes an alternative approach:

Some tablets come with a launcher that only offers wallpaper settings on long press (I have some of those as well). In this case, oben the app drawer (where you can find all your apps), and switch to the "widgets" tab (usually by swiping the page from right to left). You will see the word "Widgets" highlighted on top. Now look out for the "bookmarks" widget. You may be offered multiple of them, from "1x1" to "4x4" (the numbers here specify the size the widget will consume on your screen). You can play with them to find the one suiting you best. Long-PRess it, and the drawer behind it will "fade out" -- instead your homescreen(s) will display. Drop the widget where you want to have it.

Now it will ask you for which bookmark you want to use for the widget. Chose the bookmark you created in your browser at the beginning. Now the widget should be created on your homescreen.

Comment: Ok, I followed these steps and I can see the bookmark on my home screen with the correct title. When I tap it, it says `App isn't installed` in a Toast message (I think toast is what brings up those tiny messages)

Comment: Can you try the very same with another "normal" bookmark (i.e. one with a "normal" Internet address, like e.g. `http://www.google.com/`) -- does this pop-up the same error? Also, what browser you are using -- and would an alternative browser be an option? One last alternative (without too much mess) would be to simply create the bookmark (as you already did), and open it from within the browser itself. You could also try to send the URL in a mail message and see if this opens the browser then.

Comment: Another browser I don't think would be an option. I was able to create a "normal" bookmark. When I tap it, it says complete action using Browser or chrome.

Comment: OK, this means you already have two browsers installed. Strange that they are not offered on the other bookmark. Could you please verify the URL for "your" bookmark, if it really is `file:///Removable/MicroSD/MyApp/index.html` (including the opening `file:///`), and the path is correct? Can you open that bookmark from within the browser without any problems?

Comment: That is definitely the correct URL, even with the 3 slashes http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4775/how-can-i-open-an-html-file-i-have-copied-from-pc-to-sd-card-of-phone and yes I can click the bookmark from within the browser

Comment: I assume if you had multiple bookmark widgets available, you've tried them all (I rarely use bookmarks on my mobile devices, so I don't know what other differences those widgets have) -- in this case, I'm out of ideas...

Comment: I have whatever bookmark widgets the device came with. I wanted to test it as bare bones as possible since the devices being used are government devices and are locked down pretty tight. I appreciate your help anyway, I'll see what other options I have

Answer (score 0):

Why are you choosing to distribute via an SD Card? You can use something akin to [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), and pack it into an APK. It's still static files locally, and still being run by the local WebRenderer.

This is a bit of an alternative solution + comment -.-

Comment: You could do it that way or copy the webapp into assets folder of the source and build...

Comment: We are doing this because the contract we have is a government contract. Lot's of restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

If you can install an app from the play store without infringing on your contract, then get [Task Bomb](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.androidideas.taskbomb&hl=en).

1. Launch the app and tap Tasks
2. Tap the white plus in the top-right corner
3. Select VIEW for Action type
4. Tap Data, then tap your file manager in the popup
5. Browse to the root of your site and tap the index page
6. For Activity, select whichever app you want to use to open it

Now that you've created the task, you have to add a homescreen shortcut

1. Go to your homescreen and drop the Quick Launch shortcut to your homescreen
2. Select your task from the list, name it anything, and you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Install [open in browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.gelin.android.browser.open&hl=en) - then you can browse to the file in a manager, select the file and it will open in the web browser.  You can then also bookmark in your web browser and even put that bookmark on a widget on the desktop.

And the above app is [open source](https://bitbucket.org/gelin/open-in-browser)