# How can I view webpages locally?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, browser, html

Is there an app available on the Play Store that allows us to view websites/webpages that have been transferred to the SD Card?

I've tried several android browsers and none of them allow me to open a *.html file and actually view it as a webpage - they only show the code of the page.

I've tried using numerous File Manager apps and using the Open with... command to open them in various apps but no luck.

I did come across this page: [How can I open an HTML file I have copied from PC to SD Card of Phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4775/how-can-i-open-an-html-file-i-have-copied-from-pc-to-sd-card-of-phone) which suggests it can be done by manually typing in the entire path of the file, but I'd really prefer it if there was an app for this. Either on the Play Store or even an APK that somebody's made available online somewhere. I've yet to find one though.

Answer (score 3):

[SD Card Offline HTML Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.dadbiz.myDerivedApp&hl=en) will show those saved files locally.

[Android Open In Browser](https://code.google.com/p/android-open-in-browser/wiki/DoesntWork) states the issues, but does say Opera Bowser will work on some Samsung devices.

Comment: Pocket is great too, worth a look!